# How do I reorder a long string of concatenated date and timestamps seperated by commas using Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-datetime

I have a string type column called 'datetimes' that contains multiple dates with their timestamps, and I'm trying to extract the earliest and last dates (without the timestamps) into new columns called 'earliest_date' and 'last date'.

The problem, however, is that the dates are not in order, so it's not as straightforward as using a str.split() method to get the first and last dates in the string. I need to order them first in ascending order.

Here's an example of an entry for one of the rows: 2022-04-13 04:47:00,2022-04-07 01:58:00,2022-03-31 02:32:00,2022-03-25 11:59:00,2022-04-12 05:07:00,2022-03-29 01:46:00,2022-03-31 05:52:00,

As you can see, the order is randomized. I would like to firstly remove the timestamps which are fortunately in between a whitespace and comma, then order the dates in ascending order, and then finally get the max and min dates into two separate columns.

Can anyone please help me? Thanks in advance :)

`df['Campaign Interaction Dates'] = df['Campaign Interaction Dates'].str.replace('/','-')

def normalise(d):
if len(t := d.split('-')) == 3:
return d if len(t[0]) == 4 else '-'.join(reversed(t))
return '9999-99-99'

out = sorted(normalise(t[:10]) for t in str(df[df['Campaign Interaction Dates']]).split(',') if t)

df['out'] = out[1]

print(display(df[df['Number of Campaign Codes registered']==3]))`

Comment: So this is the string in one cell? 2022-04-13 04:47:00,2022-04-07 01:58:00,2022-03-31 02:32:00,2022-03-25 11:59:00,2022-04-12 05:07:00,2022-03-29 01:46:00,2022-03-31 05:52:00,

Comment: What do you mean by "string type column"? Are you trying to say that it is just one long string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use following code if you are not sure that date format will always be YYYY-MM-DD:

```
import datetime

string= "2022-04-13 04:47:00,2022-04-07 01:58:00,2022-03-31 02:32:00,2022-03-25 11:59:00,2022-04-12 05:07:00,2022-03-29 01:46:00,2022-03-31 05:52:00"
dates_list = [date[:10] for date in string.split(',')]
dates_list.sort(key=lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d'))
min_date, max_date = dates_list[0], dates_list[-1]
```

You can easily replace date format here

Comment: How do you know which date format to use?

Comment: Actually if date format can be different in rows of same column then it is impossible to process. And only if we have information about date format then we can use my solution

Comment: Not impossible. See my answer

Comment: Your answer covers reverse format case. It is possible to handle. I meant case when date format is not known. For example possible formats: YYYY-DD-MM, YYYY-MM-DD, DD-MM-YYYY, MM-DD-YYYY. In cases when DD <= 12 it is impossible to guess what are day and month.

Comment: I completely agree that certain date formats are ambiguous. That is why I was very specific in my answer about what can and cannot be handled in this way

Answer (score 0):

```
string = "2022-04-13 04:47:00,2022-04-07 01:58:00,2022-03-31 02:32:00,2022-03-25 11:59:00,2022-04-12 05:07:00,2022-03-29 01:46:00,2022-03-31 05:52:00"
split_string = string.split(",")
split_string.sort()

new_list = []

for i in split_string:
    temp_list = i.split()

    new_list.append(temp_list[0])

max_date = new_list[-1]
min_date = new_list[0]
```